# How to disabled tooltips/descriptions/pop-up in windows 11

Tags: popup, tooltip, desktop-application, desktop, windows-11

Cloud tooltips/descriptions/pop-up descriptions in windows 11

Hi this is quite annoying for me.
Does anyone know how to disable tooltips/descriptions/pop-up in windows 11, such as the following.
Thank you in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVeO6.png)